# (iOS) Escaping single quote in XML

Tags: ios, xml

I have written the below code in xml:

```
var invalidLastNameMessage="We&apos;re sorry, but that last name doesn&apos;t match our records.";
```

When i check in IOS devices(ipod/iphone), it should come like:

```
We're sorry, but that last name doesn't match our records.
```

But it shows like :

```
We&apos;re sorry, but that last name doesn&apos;t match our records.
```

Can anyone explains that why was it happened?

Comment: What's your XML encoding declaration? First line.

Comment: Also, what kind of XML is that with `var` statements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would not be surprised if it automatically is escaped. It seems like it escapes

```
We&apos;re
```

to

```
We&apos;apos;re
```

Did you try just feeding it a non-escaped value?